# How to stop redwood decks from creaking

Tags: wood, woodworking, deck, decking

My home was built brand new in 2016. I have a front porch and two back decks made of redwood and they all creak so badly, it's almost embarrassing...

Anyone have any tips on how to quite them down?

Comment: Was the decking nailed or screwed to the joists?

Comment: @Kris Whops. Yeah, should have mentioned that... It is all screwed down with what looks like proper screws (possibly GRK)

Comment: Can you Determine if the squeaks are from decking or the structural supports? Are there bolts and nuts that may need tightened now that deck has dried out and shrank some?